# Read H5File from a folder inside a zipped folder into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, zip, h5py

Question : Read H5File from a folder inside a zipped folder into pandas dataframe

Background : The directory structure I have looks like this:
file.zip/2019/file.h5

file.zip is the zipped folder
2019 is the folder inside the zipped folder

I can extract the folder using extractall and read the h5 file from the folder. However, looking to read it directly from the zipped folder to pandas dataframe.

Code to create a sample file:
Here is the code to recreate a sample h5 file that I am trying to use in this scenario:

Step 1:

```
import h5py
file = h5py.File('sample.h5','w')
dataset = file.create_dataset("dset",(4, 6), h5py.h5t.STD_I32BE)
file.close()
```

Step 2:
After the file is created, put it in a folder "2019". Place "2019" inside another folder called zipfolder and zip it. So now the directory structure looks like "file.zip/2019/file.h5"

Note: This is an H5py file and HDFStore. Pandas read_hdf cannot work on H5Files. Read on HDF5 documentation for more clarity on H5 Files and HDFStore. They both have different internal structure however the same .h5 extension.For reading H5 Files, h5py package is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out with the help of H5py google group:https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/h5py

`import zipfile
    import h5py
    import pandas as pd

    print(h5py.__version__)# Make sure the version is 2.9 or above
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile('zipfolder.zip')
    print(zf.namelist())# get the name of the fileobject

    fiz = zf.open('zipfolder/2019/sample.h5')

    hf = h5py.File(fiz,'r')

    print(list(hf.keys())) # To see the datasets inside h5 File

    df = pd.DataFrame(hf['dset'][:])
    df.head()`

Used h5py to read h5Files. Pandas reads only the HDFStore formats that have structured dataframe formats and doesn't read h5files as of now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip') as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if os.path.isdir(filename) and filename == "2019":
            # read the file into a pandas dataframe
            df = pd.read_hdf(z.open(os.path.join(filename, "file.h5"), 'rb'))
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: HDF from pandas apparently works on HDFStore. I usually use h5py to read it. Now I am facing challenge because I need to read it from inside a zipped folder and it doesn't work. The above code runs without error, but there is no df created. df.head() says that there is no df

Comment: please use `pd.read_hdf(z.open(os.path.join(filename, "file.h5"), 'r'))`

Comment: Tried adding the complete filepath and got this error. OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'topfolder/zipfile.zip/2019/sample.h5', errno = 20, error message = 'Not a directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Comment: Tried df = pd.read_hdf(z.open(os.path.join(filename, file.h5")), mode='r') got this
      NotImplementedError: Support for generic buffers has not been implemented. 
  df = h5py.File(z.open(os.path.join(filename, file.h5")), mode='r')
Got this : TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ZipExtFile

Comment: please change mode to `mode="rb"` to read bytes. See the edit

Comment: same error as above: the NotimplementedError and the Type error.

Comment: share your zip file

Comment: Made edits in the question and added codes for creating a sample h5 file. And added note on why pd.read_hdf doesn't work with this. I might be wrong. Please look into it and advise.Much appreciated.

Comment: May I ask, why you need to read a file in a zipped folder? Is it some kind of restriction or any space problem?

Comment: yes. Space issues. The files are huge. Dont want to place it in a directory. Reading directly from zipped folder could save space and clutter. So checking if thats possible.

Comment: I did some R&D on your problem, but again this problem `Support for generic buffers has not been implemented` is not implemented yet.