# Question regarding to opening .h5 file in zip file [python]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, zip

I have a question on how to load models weight if the .h5 file is inside the zip file. I am intended to load my machine learning model without extracting the zip file. I have a zip file called 'model.zip' now, and inside has `model.json` and `model.h5`

I first use the below method to call the json file and it works:

```
archive = ZipFile(request.data['modelfile'])

for file in archive.infolist(): 
    ext = file.filename.split('.')[-1]
    if ext == 'h5':
        model_h5_file = archive.open(file)
    elif ext == 'json':
        model_json_file = archive.open(file)

loaded_model = model_from_json(model_json_file.read())
```

I use the same way to open the h5 file, but it turns out error:

```py
loaded_model.load_weights(model_h5_file)
AttributeError: 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

What should I do if I want to use straightly load the weights from the zip file without extracting it, since it will be done in the backend...

Comment: Found the similar issue resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58171092/14290681) which can help you to access `.h5` file from zip file.

Comment: Did you get success?